# Add space and return after inline shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I used a code found online to re-size all of the pictures in a Word document to be the same size. This works as intended.

```vb
Sub Resize_All_Pictures()
'
' Resize_All_Pictures Macro
'
'
mytext = " "
Dim iShape As InlineShape

For Each iShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With iShape
        .Width = InchesToPoints(2.21)
        .Height = InchesToPoints(2.21)
    End With
Next iShape

End Sub
```

I would like to add one space after each image and a return after each row of pictures (three pictures in one row).

After running the code above:
[image]

What I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: You might be able to play with the `.WrapFormat` properties for each iShape

Comment: For an alternative approach, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/47919-post2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the shape's `Range` object. If you add a counter you can then determine whether to add a space or a new paragraph.

```
Sub Resize_All_Pictures()
    '
    ' Resize_All_Pictures Macro
    '
    '
    Dim iShape As InlineShape
    Dim count As Long

    For Each iShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With iShape
            .Width = InchesToPoints(2.21)
            .Height = InchesToPoints(2.21)
            count = count + 1
            If count Mod 3 = 0 Then
                .Range.InsertAfter vbCr
            Else
                .Range.InsertAfter " "
            End If
        End With
    Next iShape

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works very well! Do you happen to know why it starts with only one picture in the first row and then the next row will have a total of three? Thank you again!

Comment: @vognog - In my testing there were three pictures in each row. Are you sure the first is an inline shape?

Comment: Yes I believe the first is an inline shape. If I have three pictures in my document, it will put the first picture in its own row, and then return and place the following two into its next row. It seems to put the first picture into its own row! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Timothy, I was able to solve the problem! Thank you for your help!